# jQuery slider auto-play button didn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#btn-autoPlay.playoff').on('click', playOn);
$('#btn-autoPlay.playon').on('click', playOff);
```

```
function playOn() {

    $('.playoff').text("Autoplay: ON");
    timeId = setInterval(function () {
        nextSlide();
    }, 3000);
    $('.playoff').addClass('playon').removeClass('playoff');

}

function playOff() {

    $('.playon').text("Autoplay: OFF");
    clearInterval(timeId);
    $('.playon').addClass('playoff').removeClass('playon');

}
```

Details: When I first click button(#btn-autoplay.playoff), the text changes to "Autoplay: ON", as well as the class(.playoff) changes to class(.playon). But when I click the button second time, the button text doesn't change and the class is still '.playon'. What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Kindly check my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to [delegate the events](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated items.

The `body` is a static parent here and the events are watched with the help of the static parent. If some HTML gets changed dynamically by JavaScript, the connected events tend to disappear, as they are not the same old DOM Elements.

```
$("body").on('click', '#btn-autoPlay.playoff', playOn);
$("body").on('click', '#btn-autoPlay.playon', playOff);
```

So, attaching the event to a near static parent, and delegating it to the right one, will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn-autoPlay.playoff', playOn);
$(document).on('click', '#btn-autoPlay.playon', playOff);
```

Comment: Have a look at [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114163/event-fails-to-fire-after-dom-change-in-jquery-1-9#answer-16114178).